# SQL Server : select data between date range where there is missing data

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012, I have a script that inserts 4 rows of data into a table each day. The data looks like this:

[image: Complete Data]

Sometimes one or more of the rows is not inserted as the source data is incomplete. This looks like this - the second column is called `commodityID`:

[image: Missing Data]

There are times where more than one row could be missing.

I am trying to write a query that will show me what data is missing, so for the example above it would be for `commodityID = 2`. I have another table which is a calendar (lists all dates) table which I use with the query below to see if no data exists for a given date for all commodities.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Calendar] 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID, CommodityID, Price, DateEntered
                   FROM Spectron_DailyPricing
                   WHERE (CONVERT(date, DateEntered) = Calendar.date))) 
                     AND (date BETWEEN '2015-05-14' AND dateadd(day, -1,GETDATE()))
ORDER BY date asc
```

I want to be able to run a SQL query that will look through all of the data and show the date and the `commodityID` that is missing. So for the example above it would show the following.

[image: example result]

As my data spans a few years and there is the odd missing row there would be numerous results.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? Can you please share an excel demo output? Or explain precisely what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH
    CTE_Numbers AS (
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS a(CommodityID)),
    CTE_Calendar AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [Calendar] c
        CROSS JOIN CTE_Numbers n
        WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2015-05-14' AND dateadd(day, -1,GETDATE()))
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Calendar c
LEFT JOIN Spectron_DailyPricing s
    ON c.CommodityID = s.CommodityID
    AND c.date = CONVERT(date, s.DateEntered)
WHERE 
    s.CommodityID IS NULL
ORDER BY c.date asc
```